# USB ports 3.0 not working

Tags: 14.04, usb

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS alongside with Windows 7. Under Windows 7 the USB 3.0 ports are working properly but they aren't on Ubuntu. 
I'm new to Linux OSs and I don't know what to do.

Side note: I had to enable IOMMU option in BIOS in order to boot Ubuntu from USB and to install it (it seems to be a problem with Gigabyte's motherboards).

Thanks for your help, regards, Luca.